# How to extract multiple patterns from a multi-line string

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I have a string that looks like this. It's obviously a multi-line string and I would like to split it into one string per stanza.

```
{
   "timestamp":1317911700,
   "application":"system.dev",
   "metrics":{
      "qlen":0,
      "read.bytes":0,
      "write.bytes":185165.0123762,
      "busy":0.021423
   },
   "dimensions":{
      "device":"sda"
   }
}

{
   "timestamp":1317911700,
   "application":"system.fs",
   "metrics":{
      "inodes.used":246627,
      "inodes.free":28703901,
      "capacity.kb":227927024,
      "available.kb":209528472,
      "used.kb":6820512
   },
   "dimensions":{
      "filesystem":"/"
   }
}

{
   "status_code":0,
   "application":"system",
   "status_msg":"Data collected successfully"
}
```

My regex looks like this:

```
/^({\n[^}]+^})/m
```

But I am only capturing:

```
{
   "status_code":0,
   "application":"system",
   "status_msg":"Data collected successfully"
}
```

Which kinda makes sense since that's where the first curly brace is. What I am trying to do is capture from anywhere there is a /^{/ to anywhere there is a /^}/ as a single string. But I think the other curly braces in there are tr

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a real JSON parser to extract the data you want?

Comment: It's not valid JSON. It would have to look like this to be valid. [ {stanza1},{stanza2},{stanza99}]. I've already run it through a validator and it failed as is. I do not control the output so I need to capture it and munch it myself. I was wondering if I could do something with lookahead. my @foo = /somelookahead/;

Comment: Nevermind, I see that there are no commas at the end of each stanza, so JSON parsing won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a few approaches.

- There is an example somewhere in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) on how you can implement a recursive pattern. This is hard. You need to take curlies in strings into account.
- [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aBalanced) already provides means of matching balanced parens (including curlies). This might be easier, because I think it can take curlies in strings into account.
- It looks like you can simply split on blank lines.

  ```
  @json_snippets = split /^$/m, $json_snippets;
  ```
- But the most reliable solution is to use [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS)'s "incremental parser". (Search for that in its documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

```
for my $stanza (split /^$/m, $str) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: And thereafter you have valid JSON strings: 
 
foreach my $stanza ( split( /^$/m, $str ) ) { 
  my $json = decode_json( $stanza ); 
  print Dumper( $json ); 
}

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a JSON parser to properly do it, I would just split at the end of a stanza.

```
my @stanzas = split /^}\K\n\n/;
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON. It's more like a series of JSON snippets.